# Terraform read single-item list

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

In terraform's [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/media_package_channel#url) it states:

> A single item list of HLS ingest information

And then, a nested value of:

> A list of the ingest endpoints

How can I get the first item entry of the list of endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the resource was not provided, we will assume the example in the documentation:

```
resource "aws_media_package_channel" "kittens" {
  channel_id  = "kitten-channel"
  description = "A channel dedicated to amusing videos of kittens."
}
```

Given that resource, we can access the exported resource attribute with the normal namespace of `aws_media_package_channel.kittens.hls_ingest`. Since this is a single item list containing a map, we would then access `aws_media_package_channel.kittens.hls_ingest[0].ingest_endpoints`. You stated that you want the first element of this nested list, and therefore with the customary syntax for the zeroth element:

```
aws_media_package_channel.kittens.hls_ingest[0].ingest_endpoints[0]
```

where you can then access values of that map by referencing the key e.g. `url` as per normal.